# Changing color in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Can I use CSS in JQuery to change a `div`'s color slowly? Oh and one more thing, how can I add a second function to my `<div>`. Here is the code. I want to change the color back to the old one when `mouseout` happens.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#square").css({ backgroundColor: 'blue' });

        });

    }
</script>

<div id="square" onmouseover="return myFunction()">Focus on me!</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950988/jquery-change-css-attribute-slowly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it slow, give a `transition` and remove the `document.ready` as you are calling it by something not on load:

```css
#square {transition: 1s all linear;}
```

**Cross Browser Support**

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear;
-o-transition: all 1s linear;
transition: all 1s linear;
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#square").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", 'blue');
  }, function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", '');
  });
});
```

```css
#square {width: 100px; height: 100px; transition: 1s all linear;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: @AltayMazlum I added a snippet too! Check it out.

Comment: Awesome! I'll use that one too.

Comment: I'm waiting to do it. I appreciate your answer but could you check my question and i editted it.

Comment: @AltayMazlum Updatng... Wait and watch.

Comment: @AltayMazlum Check out my snippet buddy!

Comment: Oh yes now i know how to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.

Use `.animate`:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#square").animate({
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }, 500);

        });

    }
</script>
```

In this case the transition is `500` ms.

Comment: Yes, the animate function is in jquery, but to animate colors, i think you need jquery UI

Comment: You will need jQuery UI to animate colours.

Comment: @KittMedia In the same page you have referred, it says: *Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.*

Comment: If you add jQuery UI to your answer, I am happy to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.animate()` to set the css effect with delay:

```
$("#square").animate({backgroundColor: 'blue'}, 500});
```

Comment: what about slowly issue?

Comment: You will need jQuery UI to animate colours.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your code with this CSS rule

```
#square {
   transition: 1s ease background;
}
```

Comment: It’s not answering the question because the question was asked on how to do it in jQuery.